# Using jQuery Plugin Treetable with Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, treetable

I am using knockout.js and want to use the [jquery plugin treetable](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/). But I don't get it to work. Has someone build something similar using knockout.js and probably with this plugin?

I was trying to integrate it using a bindingHandler:

```
<table data-bind="treetable: tasks, treeOptions: { initialState: 'expanded' } ">
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: tasks">
    <tr data-bind="attr: { 'data-tt-id': id, 'data-tt-parent-id': parentId }">
      <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See my full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/qhgfx0ff/1/

Thanks for any hint or help!

Cheers,
TeeJay

Comment: Check if you have any error in the console of your browser.

And Can I know what the line $("#tree").treetable({initialState: "expanded"}); is about?

I donno.. But if I remove that line I got some tasks printed

Comment: look at this jsfiddle maybe it can help you:
http://jsfiddle.net/9v9LD/26/

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It works now and I'll updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbackhausen/qhgfx0ff/3/). However integrating drag and drop is the next burden.

Comment: Can I know the changes that you have done in it?

Comment: Hi. I added a the init part of the binding handler to initialize the treetable. I also recognized that I have to write "treetable" in lowercase letters (see $(element).treetable(options);).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot directly use thirdparty plugins in knockout. We need to create a custom binding for them.

Look at the section

> Custom binding handlers

in the link [here](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2014/07/knockoutjs.html) which has integrating third party widgets in knockout. You can use similar kind of logic here